# Are there any laser sensors that have a high accuracy at 200-400 mm with low laser angle?

Tags: laser, distance

I'm looking for a simple laser sensor that has these properies.

**Range and accuracy at different reflectance**

[image]

I recently wrote an [unscented Kalman filter](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Unscented-Kalman-Filter) in C code and tested it with a VL6180x laser sensor. It works very well, but the problem is that the laser angle is too wide with VL6180x. 25 degrees is too much.

I'm going to measure small objects that are about 300 ms far away.  The objects are very small - about 10mm^2. The surfaces of the objects are metal - gray.

A VL6180x can handle this, but NOT if there are objects nearby the object I want to measure. The VL6180x would detect objects that are near the target.

Is there is a similar short distance laser sensor with accuracy less than 5% and repeatabillity 1-2 mm with a laser angle less than about 10 degrees?

**Clarifying**

[image]

Comment: Why does the laser angle matter (as opposed to the width of the beam)?  If your goal is to have 10cm lateral resolution  you need a beam smaller than 10 cm, but the angle doesn't have much influence on resolution in the target plane.  Can you change the lens on your current sensor to generate the beam profile you need?

Comment: @user1850479 Thank you for your reply. I cannot change the lens on VL6180x, sorry. Yes, I need a smaller beam.

Comment: You should edit your question then, since it asks for something very different.

Comment: @user1850479 What do you mean different? Isin't ToF-lasers the same?

Comment: From your comment above, it sounded like you wanted a smaller beam rather than a smaller angle.  Your question asks for a smaller angle but not a smaller beam.  Ask a clear question or the mods will close your post.  No idea what you're asking about ToF, if that is important, also put it in your question.

Comment: @user1850479 I posted a picture that describe what I want.

Comment: @MrYui opposite of `wide` is `narrow` ... so the term is `narrow beam` or `narrower beam`

Comment: The term you're looking for is "divergence angle".  The beam angle in triangulation is usually the angle formed between the beam and the object.

Answer (score 1):

First, reducing the angle of the illumination cone will severely reduce available measurement range, because the objects visible to the sensor must be within the intersection of two cones, defined by their angles and the distance between laser and sensor.

Second, attempting to focus the beam by any means is *really bad and dangerous idea*. In fact, the datasheet specifically says

> no optics should be used with the intention of focusing the laser beam

Third, probably the only thing you can do is add some kind of non-IR reflective shroud on a *receiver* window to reduce its view angle.
It can be as simple as a piece of drinking straw with [Clearweld](http://www.clearweld.com/coatings-products.html) coat on the inside.

And finally, unless you change the wording of the question, it will most likely be closed, because right now it is plain shopping question.

Comment: So you telling me that I can use an arbitrary laser sensor and add a drinking straw that does not reflect IR light? Sure, laser is dangeours but in this case, it's a weak laser.

Comment: I am saying that reducing the illumination beam angle makes less sense than reducing the view cone of the receiver. Even very narrow beam can be reflected by the environment and cause erroneous readings. The drinking straw does reflect the IR, hence the suggestion to paint it inside. As for the danger, even weak laser accidentally focused on one's retina is a thing to avoid.

Comment: I tried the sensor from STM and it worked very well for be. Do you think I should countinue using it and add a little pipe to control the light?, or find another sensor?

Comment: An answer to that question depends on so many factors (repeatability, production volume, cost etc.) that only you can answer it.